# Is there a limit to how big a Photos library can be?

Tags: macos, photos

I have a 250gb Photos library on an external harddrive. Recently Photos has begun to crash after about 15-30 seconds of use. Every time.

I haven't been able to find any info on why. This thread suggests that it is choking on movies, and I have a lot of movies. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6985998

Is there an upper limit to how big a Photos library can be?

Comment: That thread seems to be in relation to choking during _import_ of movies, not necessarily operation. How many items do you have in your library? There is no published upper limit.

Comment: My Photos library is around 500GB and it works alright (slow, but seldom crashes). I don't have a lot of videos though (maybe 5%)

Comment: I have 30,000 items. Probably 20% movies by #, 60% movies by size.